# ADO.net to Lightswitch issue

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, visual-studio-lightswitch, ado.net-entity-data-model

I've deploy my database through ADO.net Entity Data Model by executing its diagram output query against my pre-made online database.

My database contains **Only** Lightswitch supported relations, One-Many, ZeroOne-Many & One-ZeroOne.

Finally, Attaching my database to my Lightswitch application as an external database and I was shocked by its result.

**Lightswitch converts ALL One-ZeroOne relations to One-Many relations!**

I suspect everything, retry tens of times trying to figure this strange issue out with no good news!

**Question:**

Why Lightswitch converts ALL One-ZeroOne relations to One-Many relations? Inconsistency!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved it by a brute-force-like trials :S

---

**Solution :** ( *Please don't ask me a WHY question as IDK will be my answer* )

After adding a One-to-ZeroOne Relation you might have one or two Navigation Properties added to associated tables, but

1. You **MUST** add a Foreign Key as **Scalar Property** to **the ZeroOne Table** with **Same type & `true` Nullable** properties.
2. You **MUST** adjust the **Residential Constrain** for the association by double clicking the association line itself and make **the `FK` in the ZeroOne Table dependent on the One table `Key`**.
3. Generate the database script, execute it and **Don't Update LightSwitch data source, `Delete` data source & `Attach` it again instead** as it won't update relations correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a bug, it would depend on the nullablility of your PK/FK. LightSwitch will not allow 0-1 for any key property that is not nullable.

Comment: ADO.net doesn't have foreign keys for 0-1 relations, it's just the navigation property, also navigation properties don't have a null-able option.

Comment: ALL relationships must have a FK property in the "main" table, & a PK property in the "related" table. Navigation properties just hide these from normal use, but they're still there (you can still read the ID value of a navigation property, you just can't set the ID directly), or there'd be nothing to relate the two tables on. If the FK property is NOT nullable, LightSwitch will NOT allow a 0-1 relationship. It's that simple.